# Back and Up Button with different behavior on Jetpack Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to create a destination that when I press back/up the app close. So I set the popUpTo for the start destination and set the popUpToInclusive to true.
The problem is, when I press the Back Button, app close as intended, but If I press Up Button(toolbar back arrow), activity is recreated...

nav graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/call">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:name="com.example.navigationplayground.main.CallFragment"
        android:label="Call"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_call" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/agenda"
        android:name="com.example.navigationplayground.main.AgendaFragment"
        android:label="Agenda"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_agenda" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/openDetail"
            app:destination="@id/detailFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/call"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:name="com.example.navigationplayground.main.DetailFragment"
        android:label="Detail"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail"/>

</navigation>
```

sample app: https://github.com/LipeDuoli/navPlayground

look the behavior of back and up button from detail screen

Comment: Are you meaning back arrow button on toolbar?

Comment: yes.. the back button on system work as intended. the Up button (toolbar back arrow) recreate the activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `up` and `back` have different behavior.

> **The Up button never exits your app**
>
> If a user is at the start destination, the Up button should not be shown. When your app is launched using a deep link on another app's task, Up should take users to the hierarchical parent destination and not back to the other app.

If you wan't to follow guidelines, one possible way to solve your situation is to change this line

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.call, R.id.agenda))
```

To this one

```
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.call, R.id.agenda, R.id.detailFragment))
```

That basically means that your `start` destination could be one of the list above. And `start` means that user will exit the app after back pressing on this screen.

More details:

- [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-principles)
- [Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-ui)

Comment: _Up button never exits your app_, so my approach is wrong.. but is a little odd the up button reload the activity..
thx man